# Critical error when trying to implement logistic regression

Tags: python, pycharm, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement logistic regression (using PyCharm), and for certain values of learning_rate my computer *shuts down*, and the .py file gets empty (even if saved). For me this behavior is completely unexplainable, and not something I can degub myself (well, because computer dies every time I try).

What can possibly cause it? Is it somehow connected to PyCharm, or it's something bad in the code that I don't see?

Specifically, last crash happened when I changed `alpha = 0.001` in `logReg.py` to `alpha = 0.01`. For smaller values it works ok, and costs decrease on every iteration as expected.

I am using this data set: https://www.kaggle.com/keplersmachines/kepler-labelled-time-series-data
And here is the code I have so far: https://github.com/iegorval/neural_nets

Update: I went to check on another PC, and it was fine (and actually cost even seemed to converge). So what can be the problem? PyCharm, compiler, computer, OS problems? The hardware on the first PC is much more powerful.

Comment: What exactly does it mean that your computer *shuts down*? Does it initiate a normal shutdown sequence, does it freeze/bluescreen/crash? Regarding the solution, I'm afraid no one will be able to help you (yet) with the problem but yourself. First you need to narrow down the problem: 1. Remove any irrelevant code so that the problem still persists. 2. reduce the code to a single file, unless you find that using multiple source files is the cause of the problem. 3. Run it without pycharm to see if that is che cause.

Comment: Bluescreen and restart. I understand that maybe no one will be able to help, but maybe someone notice some piece of code causing it. I am also trying to deal with it somehow, but it's tricky, especially because it caused my PC to bluescreen 4 time during one morning.

Comment: If it's not an instantaneous blue screen, are you able to watch memory consumption while the program is running?

Comment: No, it's instantaneous.

Comment: Update: I went to check on another PC, and it was fine (and actually cost even seemed to converge). So what can be the problem? PyCharm, compiler, computer, OS problems? The hardware on the first PC is much more powerful.